# How can I do my query return distinct ID

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have table that put some status in a data.

For example:

**Table San_Proposta**

```
Proposta_Id    Status_Id   Imovel_Id
1              1           12
2              1           12
3              3           12
4              4           12
5              5           12
```

I want to do a query that return all Imovel_id that has the status_id equals 3, or 4, or 5, in my table San_Proposta.

My query returns the same imovel_id (12), more then once because exists the status_id equals 3, 4 and 5 to this imovel_id. How can I do this query to return just once the imovel_id that has status_id equal 3, 4 or 5 in my table san_proposta ?

This is just an example what I want,

my real query is this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT San_Proposta.Imovel_Id, San_Logradouro.Descricao, San_Endereco.Logradouro, 
San_Imovel.Numero, San_TipoComplemento.Descricao AS Expr1, San_Imovel.Complemento, 
San_Imovel.TipoDsc1, San_Transacao.TransacaoSigla, San_Transacao.Transacao_ID, 
COUNT(San_Proposta.StatusProposta_Id) AS NumeroProposta, 
CASE WHEN SN.ValidaCaptacao = 1 
AND SN.ValidaVenda = 0 
THEN 'AguardandoVenda' ELSE 'Nao' END as FoundInSanNegocio, 
San_Proposta.DataHora 
FROM San_Proposta LEFT JOIN San_Negocio SN 
ON San_Proposta.Proposta_ID = SN.Proposta_ID JOIN San_Imovel 
ON San_Proposta.Imovel_Id = San_Imovel.Imovel_Id JOIN San_Endereco 
ON San_Imovel.Endereco_Id = San_Endereco.Endereco_Id JOIN San_Logradouro 
ON San_Endereco.Logradouro_Id = San_Logradouro.Logradouro_Id JOIN San_TipoComplemento 
ON San_Imovel.TipoComplemento_Id = San_TipoComplemento.TipoComplemento_Id 
JOIN San_Transacao ON San_Imovel.Transacao_ID = San_Transacao.Transacao_ID 
JOIN San_Credenciada ON San_Imovel.Credenciada_Id = San_Credenciada.Credenciada_Id 
WHERE (San_Imovel.Credenciada_Id = 10 OR San_Proposta.Credenciada_Id = 10)
AND San_Proposta.StatusProposta_Id IN (3,4,5,6,7) 
AND San_Proposta.DataHora BETWEEN '20120227' AND DATEADD(day,1,'20120305') 
GROUP BY San_Proposta.Imovel_Id, San_Logradouro.Descricao, San_Endereco.Logradouro, 
San_Imovel.Numero, San_TipoComplemento.Descricao, San_Imovel.Complemento, 
San_Imovel.TipoDsc1, San_Transacao.TransacaoSigla, San_Transacao.Transacao_ID, 
San_Proposta.StatusProposta_Id, SN.ValidaCaptacao, SN.ValidaVenda, San_Proposta.DataHora 
ORDER BY San_Proposta.DataHora DESC
```

**@Updated**

```
San_Imovel has the Imovel_Id as Primary Key.
San_Proposta has Proposta_Id as Primary Key and Imovel_Id as Foreign Key.
San_Negocio has Negocio_Id as Primary Key and Proposta_Id as Foreign Key.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the `distinct` keyword:

```
select distinct Imovel_Id
from San_Proposta
where Status_Id   in (3,4,5)
```

or

```
select Imovel_Id
from San_Proposta
where Status_Id   in (3,4,5)
group by Imovel_Id
```

Comment: I tryied but, it returns more then once

Comment: it should not if you are using only Imovel_Id column in select, also i have updated the answer

Comment: I'm using more then one column.

Answer (score 0):

Does that help?

```
SELECT distinct Imovel_Id FROM San_Proposta WHERE status_id IN(3,4,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Distinct Imovel_id from San_Propsta where status_Id in (3,4,5)
```